# How to delete file after it is processed from Sftp.InboundStreamingAdapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

I am currently processing .csv files from a remote SFTP server, transforming them and placing them on a Kafka topic. I know we are able to delete the files after it is processed using an `Sftp.inboundAdapter`. I was curious if there was a way we can get this functionality with the `Sftp.InboundStreamingAdapter`? Is there another flow I would need to add in, or is there some way I can delete using the properties provided?

I can provide more code if the entire flow if needed.
Thanks

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpFileTransferFlow(SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory,
                                                IntegrationFlowProperties properties,
                                                MessageChannel inboundFilesMessageChannel) {

        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(new RemoteFileTemplate<>(sftpSessionFactory))
                          .filter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(properties.getRemoteFilePattern()))
                          .remoteDirectory(properties.getRemoteDirectory()),
                      e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                            .autoStartup(true)
                            .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000)))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "DataSftpToKafkaIntegrationFlow",
                     "headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + + T(java.io.File).separator  + headers['file_remoteFile']")
                .channel(inboundFilesMessageChannel)
                .get();
    }
```

EDIT:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow readCsvFileFlow(MessageChannel inboundFilesMessageChannel,
                                           QueueChannel kafkaPojoMessageChannel) {
        
        return IntegrationFlow.from(inboundFilesMessageChannel)
                              .split(Files.splitter()
                                          .markers(true)
                                          .charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                          .firstLineAsHeader("myHeaders")
                                          .applySequence(true))
                              // .transform(new StreamToEmailInteractionConverter()) // TODO: Figure this out so it doesn't get put on topic as .csv
                              .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
                              .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG,
                                   "DataSftpToKafkaIntegrationFlow",
                                   m -> "Payload: " + m.getPayload())
                              .channel(kafkaPojoMessageChannel)
                              .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow publishToKafkaFlow(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate,
                                              MessageChannel kafkaProducerErrorRecordChannel,
                                              QueueChannel kafkaPojoMessageChannel) {

        return IntegrationFlow.from(kafkaPojoMessageChannel)
                              .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG,
                                   "DataSftpToKafkaIntegrationFlow", e -> "Payload: " + e.getPayload())
                              .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
                                           .topic(KAFKA_TOPIC),
                                      e -> e.id("KafkaProducer"))
                              .routeByException(r -> r
                                      .channelMapping(KafkaProducerException.class, kafkaProducerErrorRecordChannel)
                                      .defaultOutputChannel("errorChannel"))
                              .get();
    }
```

After this entire flow is completed I would like to delete the file we just processed from the remote SFTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` works in two phases: Copy remote files into local dir, and then emit messages for those local files. The `deleteRemoteFiles` option is for copying from remote to local phase. That's where we don't need remote files any more and we deal only with local copies downstream.

The streaming source opens an `InputStream` for remote files and keeps it that way until you close it manually. That's why we don't have a explicit option to delete remote files.

You can perform remote file removal using an `SftpOutboundGateway` with an `rm` command. This gateway could be as a second subscriber to that `inboundFilesMessageChannel` when you make it as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and when you have closed already that `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE` from message headers.

However I think we can come up with an option like `removeFileOnClose` on the `AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource` and and perform `rm` when `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE` is closed.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, I can set up an SftpOutboundGateway to remove the file after processing from the inboundFilesMessageChannel? Let me post my other flows here, just so you can see the whole flow, we need to delete the file after it has been pushed to Kafka.

Comment: Or if there is multiple files delete all of the processed ones after the entire stream is closed.

Comment: No, there is no way to remove multiple files. You also can use an `SftpRemoteFileTemplate` directly instead of `SftpOutboundGateway`.

Comment: So the stream will process all the files together and not treat them as individual files? What about when the entire stream is closed is there a way to delete all of the files on the remote server? Or is it better in this case not to use the InboundStreamingAdapter?

Comment: I see that you use a `Files.splitter()` over there it emit multiple records to Kafka based on file content. You do that sequentially, so my suggestion about `PublishSubscribeChannel` for your `inboundFilesMessageChannel` still applies. And you just would have another flow subscribed to this channel to perform close and delete.

Comment: Your understanding is a bit wrong. The streaming channel adapter is about an `InputStream` as a message payload to emit for a single file. It is not a stream of remote files.

Comment: Couldn't I add advice in the initial Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter, so when processing is completed I can send a request to remove the file on remote server? I'm overthinking the PublishSubscribeChannel implementation I think.

Comment: No, you cannot. An advice on an `AbstractPollingEndpoint` is done around a `MessageSource.receive()` method, but in your case you still send the message into a channel downstream. And since it is an `InputStream` for a remote file, deleting it prematurely would lead to the problem. Not sure what wrong you see with a `PublishSubscribeChannel`, but you can consider a `WireTap` instead on that `inboundFilesMessageChannel`.

Comment: The SftpOutboundGateway worked, by adding a `nullChannel()` to the end